# How to redirect a 404 to https in nginx?

Tags: nginx, redirect, https, http-status-code-404

For some reason a Redmine installation keeps redirecting some https requests to http.

I'd like to change 404 response for the vhost the pages are redirected to back to the https it should have gone to. What is the syntax for that.

I am trying this link [Using Nginx how do I redirect single URIs from http to https?](https://serverfault.com/questions/314507/using-nginx-how-do-i-redirect-single-uris-from-http-to-https) as well, but this is the first to come to mind.

Answer (score 0):

First at all, check your Redmine's configuration:

Look at *Administration* > *Settings* > *General* Then **Protocol**.

It should be set to **HTTPS** and not **HTTP**.  This is certainly your problem.

Otherwise, for nginx if you want to redirect http trafic to https:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    rewrite ^ https://www.example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
server {
    listen  443 default ssl;
    server_name www.example.com;
    ...
```

Comment: The Protocol is properly set. I think it is a bug in Redmine. It only happens on certain 1. the top level project and 2. when I submit changes or create a new issue

Comment: Strange behaviour... I've never seen that yet ! What the logs are saying ?